# Overriding default login method showing These credentials do not match our records Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to override laravel default Login method and trying to use my own logic there. In my login blade, i'm using an input field named 'identifiers' instead of email field. When i submit my form i'm getting `These credentials do not match our records` error. What i override:

the login.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('login') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="identifiers"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username or UserID or Email or Mobile No." aria-describedby="identifiers" name="identifiers" value="{{ old('identifiers') }}">
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('identifiers'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('identifiers') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="password"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="password" name="password">
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm  pull-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                Sign In
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

for routing, i'm using default one

```
Auth::routes();
```

path: app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Sign In';

        return view('auth.login', array('data' => $this->data));
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'identifiers' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request)
    {
        pr($request->all());die;

    }
}
```

As per documentation i need to override the `authenticate` method in LoginController. But the request never reached to that method even if i override it. It is redirecting me back to login page with following error. What i missed! can anyone tell!

Comment: Would you please share `// my logics here......` part?

Comment: the problem is there.. it is not even reaching to authenticate method...i put print_r to check if the request is receiving or not

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that `identifiers` instead of email to retrieve your user. By default Laravel search email address in your user table. See [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-authenticating)

you should add the function in your login controller

```
public function username()
{
    return 'identifiers';
}
```

your login controller looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Sign In';

        return view('auth.login', array('data' => $this->data));
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'identifiers' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'identifiers';
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        return true; 

    }
}
```

its works form me.

Comment: But laravel documentation shows that we can use this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users..

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed read the documentation carefully. it said that if you are not using the default login controller then you can log in in this way. then you should change the router also.  like this Router::post('/login', 'LoginController@authenticate') . I think you understand.

Comment: i used your method too..but still it's not reaching to this method either..

Comment: then please add full controller and router in your question